# Equivalent of select into in sql script

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble setting the job_num_to_run variable to the actual job_id in a sql script.  The below example has the job num to run being set to the string literal "select max...) and doesn't evaluate to the value.  I've tried a number of different ways without success.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
def job_num_to_run = select max(job_id) from job_table;

update job_table
   set processed = 'Y' where job_id = &job_num_to_run;
```

Comment: What *type* of SQL?  Distinct SQL products are very different when it comes to things like variables and procedures.

Comment: THis is for an oracle db

Comment: @eric please check my solution, they work for several db engines.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @job_num_to_run INT = select max(job_id) from job_table;

update job_table
set processed = 'Y' 
where job_id = @job_num_to_run;
```

INT could be whatever the datatype of job_id is

Answer (score 1):

```
Update job_table set processed = 'Y' where job_id = (select max(job_id) from job_table)
```

Comment: +1. It's best to avoid using the procedural language for something that can be accomplished with a single SQL statement.